# plyr count excludes unobserved values

Tags: r

I have a dataframe of people classified as cases (`df$case==1`) and non-cases (`df$case==0`), along with their responses to 3 items that could take the values of 0 to 3.

For each item, I want to calculate the proportion of cases who have a value of 2 or 3 and the proportion of non-cases who have a value of 2 or 3. Then I want to take the difference in proportions between cases and non-cases for each item.

For instance, in the toy dataset provided, there are 8 cases and 8 non-cases. For `item1`, 2 of the 8 non-cases have a value of 2 or 3 (proportion is 0.25). On the same item, 6 of the 8 cases have a value of 2 or 3 (proportion is 0.75. The difference in proportions (or gradient) is of course 0.50.

`item2` has a gradient of 0 because the proportion for both groups is 0.50.

`item3` has a problem. The observed values do not include 0, 1, or 3, and `plyr::count(df, c("case", v))` excludes these values from the table `fr`. Therefore, my very ugly loop is looking for zero counts in `fr` that don't exist.

I am optimistic there is a 3 line tidyverse solution that will put an end to this madness ;)

```
# setup
  df <- data.frame(case=c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1),
                   item1=c(0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,0,0,0,0,3,3,3,3),
                   item2=c(0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3),
                   item3=c(2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2))

  vars <- c("item1", "item2", "item3")
  itemGradient <- as.data.frame(vars)
  gradient <- as.data.frame(NULL)

# calculate response frequencies by case-ness
  gr <- 1
  for (v in vars) {
    fr <- plyr::count(df, c("case", v))
    gradient[gr, 1] <- v                # item
    gradient[gr, 2] <- 0                # case
    gradient[gr, 3] <- fr[1, 3]         # option 0
    gradient[gr, 4] <- fr[2, 3]         # option 1
    gradient[gr, 5] <- fr[3, 3]         # option 2
    gradient[gr, 6] <- fr[4, 3]         # option 3
    gradient[gr+1, 1] <- v              # item
    gradient[gr+1, 2] <- 1              # case
    gradient[gr+1, 3] <- fr[5, 3]       # option 0
    gradient[gr+1, 4] <- fr[6, 3]       # option 1
    gradient[gr+1, 5] <- fr[7, 3]       # option 2
    gradient[gr+1, 6] <- fr[8, 3]       # option 3
    gr <- gr+2
  }
  names(gradient) <- c("item", "case", "r0", "r1", "r2", "r3")

# calculate proportion with values 2 or 3 by case
  gradient[is.na(gradient)] <- 0
  gradient$n <- rowSums(gradient[, c("r0", "r1", "r2", "r3")])
  gradient$r2or3 <- rowSums(gradient[, c("r2", "r3")])
  gradient$prop.r2or3 <- gradient$r2or3/gradient$n
  gradient

# calculate gradient score
  grad <- diff(gradient$prop.r2or3)
  grad <- grad[seq(1, length(grad), 2)]
  itemGradient <- data.frame(cbind(itemGradient, grad))
  names(itemGradient) <- c("item", "gradient")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does it.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- data_frame(case=c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1),
                 item1=c(0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,0,0,0,0,3,3,3,3),
                 item2=c(0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3),
                 item3=c(2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2))

df %>% 
  group_by(case) %>% 
  summarise_all(funs(sum(. %in% 2:3)/n())) %>% 
  gather("item", "value", -case) %>% 
  spread(case, value) %>% 
  mutate(diff = `1` - `0`)

#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>    item   `0`   `1`  diff
#>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 item1  0.25  0.75   0.5
#> 2 item2  0.50  0.50   0.0
#> 3 item3  1.00  1.00   0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using dplyr:

```
df2 = df %>% 
group_by(case) %>%
summarise(prop1=sum(item1 %in% c(2,3)/n()),
prop2=sum(item2 %in% c(2,3)/n()),
prop3=sum(item3 %in% c(2,3)/n()))
```

This returns:

```
   case prop1 prop2 prop3
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     0  0.25   0.5     1
2     1  0.75   0.5     1
```

Then you can take the differences:

```
grad = df2[2,2:4]-df2[1,2:4]

  prop1 prop2 prop3
   0.5     0     0
```